# Hide/show text in body on hover of child element

Tags: html, css, hover

I'd like to initially hide text in my body, but show it once an element in a child div is hovered over.  So In this case, I want them both to initially start out as `display: none` but then when I hover over the letter "H" I want "Text A" to show.  When I hover over letter "E" I want "Text B" to show.  I don't want to put my #content elements inside of my #word elements.  I want to keep them as separate divs.

Any Ideas?

(See Fiddle below)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="word">
    <h1><a id="h" class= "letter" href=#>H</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="e" class= "letter" href=#>E</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="l" class= "letter" href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="l2"class= "letter" href=#>L</a></h1>
    <h1><a id="o" class= "letter" href=#>O</a></h1> 
</div>

<div id="content">
    <div id="textA">Text A</div>
    <div id="textB">Text B</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body {
    font-family: 'Chango', cursive;
    font-size: 115px;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background: black;
    }

    #name {
    position:absolute; 
    height:100%; 
    width: 70%;
    display: table;
    padding: 0 15% 0 15%;
    background: black;
    }

    h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    height: 1em;

    }

    a {
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 89%;
    overflow: hidden;

    }

    a:visited, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    /*color: #E8E8E8;*/

    }

    a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 3px -3px 0px black, -2px 2px 5px #0056b2;

    }

    a:hover {
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
    color: white;
    }
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ADfhj/1/

PS- I've tried the following CSS to no avail:

```
#textA {
display: none;
}

#word:hover #textA {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't hide and show external elements with CSS. I think this is a job for some simple JS.

Comment: CSS currently has no way of referencing sibling elements like this. You'll need a JavaScript solution

Comment: See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hGp7P/1/  It looks like sibling divs are changing.

Comment: @Keven you can modify direct siblings, but here you're traveling up the DOM then over then back down (`a:hover` [up to] `h1` [up to] `#word` [over to sibling] `#content` [down to child] `#textA`).

Comment: I came so close to getting it without JavaScript. Unfortunately, CSS cannot change the z-index on hover, otherwise I would've figured it out.

Comment: @Jamil +1 for trying... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way achieving it using css only. However you can try simple javascript/jquery.

```
 $('.letter').mouseover(function(){
    var cont = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#content>div').hide();
    $('#text_'+cont).fadeIn();
});
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADfhj/2/)

Comment: Yep, even though it's not CSS it still works well and there is minimal coding.  Thanks!